# Leaflet - get latitude and longitude of a marker inside a pop-up

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I use the Leaflet Draw plugin.
My goal is to create markers and show a pop up in which I can get latitude and longitude coordinates.
I manage to get these coordinates with a javascript alert but I definitely don't know how to put the coordinates into my pop up.

Here is the snippet :

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
            map.on('click', function(e) {
                var lat = e.latlng.lat;
                var lng = e.latlng.lng;
                alert ("Latitude : " + lat + "\nLongitude : " + lng);
        }),

            layer.bindPopup(
            'e.latlng.lat');
        }

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

But it does not work. The pop up shows "e.latlng.lat" whereas I'd want to have **the exact value**.
Have you any solutions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    map.addLayer(layer);

    if (type === 'marker') {    
        layer.bindPopup('LatLng: ' + layer.getLatLng()).openPopup();
    }

});
```

Comment: Great, it fits perfectly to what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Comment: Is there an updated answer to this question? I am getting a warning in the console when I click in the map. ```MouseEvent.mozPressure is deprecated. Use PointerEvent.pressure instead.```

Answer (score 1):

It return lat & lng on the map when mouse clicked

```
map.on('click', function(e){
  var lt = String(e.latlng.lat),
  lg = String(e.latlng.lng);
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(lt + " " + lg)
    .openOn(map);
});
```