# Leaflet - get the first three decimals of Longitude and Latitude

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, leaflet

My goal is to get Latitude and Longitude coordinates as soon as I draw a marker.
I managed to do that with that snippet (see [Leaflet - get latitude and longitude of a marker inside a pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417843/leaflet-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-marker-inside-a-pop-up)) :

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
var type = e.layerType,
layer = e.layer;

map.addLayer(layer);

if (type === 'marker') {    
    layer.bindPopup('LatLng: ' + layer.getLatLng()).openPopup();
}

});
```

But I'd like to get the first three decimals of latitude and longitude, like 35.**567** and 105.**891**.
Is it possible to do that with Leaflet and how ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
layer.getLatLng().lat.toFixed(3)
```

See [the JavaScript number object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).